# What is the difference between mockery and stubthat?

Tags: r, unit-testing, mocking, stub

I'm developing an R package and am realizing I need to stub some functions because my tests are consuming way too much time and memory. I've done some research and have found two competing packages: [`mockery`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mockery/versions/0.4.1) and [`stubthat`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stubthat/versions/1.2.1). Both are fairly new (at the time of writing: May 2018), but `mockery` seems to be more popular, perhaps because it has been around slightly longer.

Does anyone have experience with these two packages? Could anyone help me understand some of the differences between the two?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so, especially [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (the entire page, not just the short list of items at the top), before posting your next question here.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited the question so it's hopefully more acceptable now.